# If $t\mapsto X_t$ is continuous almost everywhere and $(X_t)$ has independent increments, then $X_t - X_s$ follows a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, brownian-motion

The following statements can be found at Glasserman's Monte Carlo Methods in Financial Engineering.

> Given a stochastic process $(X_t)_{t\in [0,T]},$ if

> $(i)$ the mapping $t\mapsto X_t$ is continuous almost everywhere on $[0,T],$ and

> $(ii)$ $X_t$ has independent increments (ie for any $\{0\leq t_0<t_1<\dots <t_n\leq T\}$, all increments $\{ W(t_n) - W(t_{n-1}), W(t_{n-1}) - W(t_{n-2}),...,W(t_1)-W(t_0)\}$ are independent.)  and $X_t - X_s$ has mean $0$ and variance $t - s$ for all $s<t,$

> then $X_t - X_s$ follows a normal distribution.

When I tried to show that $X_t- X_s$ follows a normal distribution, I tried to show that its MGF is the same as a normal distribution, that is, if $Y = X_t - X_s$, then
$$\mathbb{E} [e^{uY}] = e^{\frac{1}{2} u^2(t-s)^2}.$$
However, I am not able to do it.
Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: What you are trying to show is that Brownian motion (with drift) is the only continuous Lévy process. As far as I know, there is no elementary proof of this fact and you have to use the Lévy-Itô decomposition. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lévy_process#Lévy–Khintchine_representation)

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is solved in [here (see Theorem 2 and proof)](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/06/16/continuous-processes-with-independent-increments/) in full detail using *Itô's lemma*.

On OP's demand, below I outline the main steps of the proof. First note that using the independences of the increments, we have that the characteristic function of $X_t-X_s$ is

$$
\mathbb E[e^{ia(X_t-X_s)}] = \phi(t,a)/\phi(s,a),\;\forall a \in \mathbb R,
$$
where $\phi(t,a):=\mathbb E[e^{ia(X_t-X_0)}]$ for all $(t,a) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$. The proof then proceeds as follows.

- *Step 1:* Show that (see Lemma 3) there exists a unique continuous function $\psi:\mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that for all $(t,a) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$, it holds that

  - $\psi(0,a)=0$,
  - $\mathbb E[e^{ia(X_t-X_0)}] = e^{\psi(t,a)}$,
  - $e^{iX_t - \psi(t,a)}$ is a martingale (w.r.t the [natural filtration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_filtration) of the process $X$).
- *Step 2:* Show that there exists a continuous function $\hat{b}:\mathbb R_+ \to \mathbb R$ such that for all $(t,a) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$, it holds that

  - $\hat{X}_t := X_t - \hat{b}_t$ is a martingale,
  - $ia(X_t-X_0)-\psi(t,a)-a\hat{X}_t/2$ is a square-integrable supermartingale.
- *Step 3:* Show that (see Lemma 5) for every $(t,a) \in \mathbb R_+ \times \mathbb R$, it holds that $\psi(t,a) := iab_t - \sigma_t^2 a^2/2$, where $b_t := \mathbb E[X_t-X_0]$ and $\sigma_t := \mathbb E[\hat{X}_t^2]$.

Putting things together, you've got that for $0 \le s \le t$,
$$
\mathbb E[e^{ia(X_t-X_s)}] = e^{\psi(t,a)} = e^{ia(b_t-b_s)-(\sigma_t^2-\sigma_s^2)a^2/2},
$$
which is the characteristic function of a normal distribution with mean $b_t$ and variance $\sigma_t^2-\sigma_s^2 \ge 0$.

Comment: It might be better if you can provide a summary of the list of ideas used in Theorem 2...

Comment: @Idonknow See updated post.